Where is my mistake of derive Ricci identity
I want to show the red line in picture below. Since $X$ is a vector field,  I think $X=X^k \partial_k$.
After  help of   Roland F  and Kurt G. ,  I revised my calculations:
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_i \nabla_j X^k  -  \nabla_j \nabla_i X^k
&=\nabla_i \nabla_j (X^k \partial_k)  -  \nabla_j \nabla_i (X^k \partial_k)
\\
&=X^k(\nabla_i \nabla_j \partial_k  -  \nabla_j \nabla_i \partial_k)
\\
&=X^k  R_{ijk}{}^p \partial_p
=X^k  R_{ijkl}~ g^{lp} \partial_p
\\
&=-X^kR_{ijlk} ~g^{lp} \partial_p
=-X^kR_{ij}{}^p{}_k   \partial_p
\\
&=-X^pR_{ij}{}^k{}_p   \partial_k
=-X^pR_{ij}{}^k{}_p
\end{align}
$$
But it is not same with the red line of picture below.  Where is my mistake ?

Picture below is from List of formulas in Riemannian geometry  of Wiki



Seems to come from the the antsymmetry in p,k. Normally $k$ is the first index. $${R_{ijp}}^k \to R_{ijpk}\to R_{pkij}\to -R_{kpij}  \to -{R^k}_{pij}$$

Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/ricci-identity-riemann-curvature-tensor-and-covectors (basically the same problem of mixing up the location of the raised index)

@RolandF   Thanks. Do you have any ideas for dealing with the sign confusion? When I read a paper, I have to guess which notations the author uses.

If one understands that $R$ is a Lie-algebra valued (antisymmetric matrix generator of rotation)  2-form (2-area integrand),  $$e_k\to { e_i \ {R^i}k }{j l} dx^j\wedge dx^l$$ describing the linear map of the tangent basis $e_i$ onto itself if moved around a small paralellogram $dx^k\wedge dx^l$ its clear that, all indices lowered, the two pairs are antisymmetric. The symmetry of the two pairs is a consequence of the symmetry of the Levi-Civita $\nabla_i e_k = e_l{ (\Gamma^l_k)}_i$ between tangent and derivative index, i.e. self-parallel, torsion free parallel transport.

You wrote "I revised my calculations, but they're still a little off. Could you help me figure out what the problem is ?"

I am telling you that you have in mind convention (7) in my answer (which is not Wikipedia's). How else do you transition from the second to the third $=$ sign? Also: inserting $\partial_k$ and dropping it at will shows that you lack the understanding of the difference between tensor components $R_{ijk}{}^p$ and the tensor itself that carries $\partial_k$ and $dx^q,.$

@KurtG.  $\nabla_i \nabla_j (X^k \partial_k)  -  \nabla_j \nabla_i (X^k \partial_k)
=X^k(\nabla_i \nabla_j \partial_k  -  \nabla_j \nabla_i \partial_k)$  is because $R(X,Y)(fZ)=fR(X,Y)Z$.  I often get confused tensor components and tensor, since the abstract index notation  looks like tensor component.

That is true but what has that to do with $R_{ijk}{}^p,?$ On the first page of Misner, Thorne & Wheeler they are talking about this. I found other conventions and will compile a list. I recommend that you work on your confusions.

@KurtG.  Thanks, I understand where is the problem.  In Wiki, (6) is used, but in my calculate (7) is used.  I was too impetuous to read your answer carefully.

WP defines
$$\tag1
R_{ijk}{}^l=\partial_j\Gamma^l_{ik}-\partial_i\Gamma^l_{jk}+\Gamma^p_{ik}\Gamma^l_{jp}-\Gamma^p_{jk}\Gamma^l_{ip}\,.
$$
With
$$\tag2
\nabla_j\,\partial_p=\nabla_{\partial_j}\partial_p=\Gamma^l_{jp}\partial_l
$$
this becomes
\begin{align}\tag3
R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l&=
(\partial_j\Gamma^l_{ik})\partial_l-(\partial_i\Gamma^l_{jk})\partial_l+\Gamma^p_{ik}\nabla_j\partial_p-\Gamma^p_{jk}\nabla_i\partial_p\\[2mm]\tag4
&=(\partial_j\Gamma^l_{ik})\partial_l-(\partial_i\Gamma^l_{jk})\partial_l+\Gamma^l_{ik}\nabla_j\partial_l-\Gamma^l_{jk}\nabla_i\partial_l\,.
\end{align}
Using
$$\tag5
\nabla_j(X^l\partial_l)=(\partial_jX^l)\,\partial_l+X^l\,\nabla_j\partial_l=
(\partial_jX^l)\,\partial_l+X^l\,\Gamma^p_{jl}\partial_p
$$
with $X^l=\Gamma^l_{ik}$ and $X^l=\Gamma^l_{jk}$ we get
$$\tag6
R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l=\nabla_j\big(\Gamma^l_{ik}\partial_l)-\nabla_i\big(\Gamma^l_{jk}\partial_l\big)=\nabla_j\nabla_i\partial_k-\nabla_i\nabla_j\partial_k\,.
$$
Note the order of $i$ and $j$ on the RHS of (6). I would not be surprised if
a lot of other sources prefer the convention
$$\tag7
R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l=\nabla_i\nabla_j\partial_k-\nabla_j\nabla_i\partial_k\,
$$
which also seems what you had in mind.
WP also defines
$$\tag8
R^i{}_{jkl}=\partial_k\Gamma^i_{lj}-\partial_l\Gamma^i_{kj}+\Gamma^i_{kp}\Gamma^p_{lj}-\Gamma^i_{lp}\Gamma^p_{kj}
$$
which, by swapping $l\leftrightarrow i,k\leftrightarrow j\,,$ we can write as
$$\tag{8'}
R^l{}_{kji}=\partial_j\Gamma^l_{ik}-\partial_i\Gamma^l_{jk}+\Gamma^l_{jp}\Gamma^p_{ik}-\Gamma^l_{ip}\Gamma^p_{jk}\,.
$$
This shows that the RHS of (1) and (8') agree. The LHS of those equations also agree due to the (anti)symmetries of $R_{ijkl}$:
$$\tag9
R_{ijk}{}^l=g^{lm}R_{ijkm}=g^{lm}R_{kmij}=g^{lm}R_{mkji}=R^l{}_{kji}\,.
$$
In short: WP is self-consistent.
Now to the list that shows the conventions in various literatures.
It begins with different conventions for the tensor itself:
$$\tag{10}
R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z\,,
$$
versus
$$\tag{11}
R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_{[Y,X]}Z\,.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{source}&\text{tensor}&\text{components}\\
\hline
\text{Carroll} & (10) & R^i{}_{jkl}\partial_i=R(\partial_k,\partial_l)\partial_j  \\
\text{Frankel} & \cdot & \cdot \\
\text{Jost} & \cdot  & \cdot \\
\text{Misner, Thorne & Wheeler} & \cdot &  \cdot \\
\text{Nakahara} & \cdot &\cdot \\
\text{Spivak} & (10) &  R^i{}_{jkl}\partial_i=R(\partial_k,\partial_l)\partial_j \\
\hline
\text{Needham} & (10) & R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l=R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k\\
\text{Lee} & \cdot & \cdot\\
\text{Liang & Zhou} & \cdot & \cdot \\
\text{Petersen} & (10) & R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l=R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k\\
\hline
\text{Lugo} & (10) & R^i{}_{jkl}\partial_i=R(\partial_k,\partial_j)\partial_l  \\
\hline
\text{Do Carmo} & (11) & R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l=R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k  \\
\hline
\end{array}

A dot means that the convention is the same as in the previous line.

Jost effectively writes $R^i_{jkl}$ which makes it unclear if $i$ is the
first or the last index.

Do Carmo writes $R^\ell_{ijk}$ which makes it unclear if $\ell$ is the
first or the last index.

The symmetries of $R_{ijkl}$ that led to (9) are the same, regardless
if the components came from (10) or (11). However, Needham's and Lee's components are the negative of those of Carroll et.al:
$$\tag{12}
R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k=R_{ijk}{}^l\partial_l\stackrel{(9)}=R^l{}_{kji}\partial_l=R^m{}_{kji}\partial_m\,.
$$
If we now rename $i\mapsto k,j\mapsto l,k\mapsto j$ we get
$$\tag{13}
R(\partial_k,\partial_l)\partial_j=R^m{}_{jlk}\partial_m=-R^i{}_{jkl}\partial_i\,
$$
due to the anti-symmetry in $k$ and $l\,.$


Carroll S., Spacetime and Geometry. 
Do Carmo M., Riemannian Geometry. 
Frankel T., The Geometry of Physics.
Jost J., Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis.
Lee J., Riemannian Manifolds - An Introduction to Curvature. (1997)
Lee J., Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds. (2018)
Liang W., Zhou B., Differential Geometry and General Relativity.
Lugo G., Differential Geometry in Physics.
Misner Ch.W., Thorne K.S., Wheeler J.A., Gravitation.
Nakahara M., Geometry, Topology and Physics.
Needham T., Visual Differential Geometry and Forms.
Petersen P., Riemannian Geometry.
Spivak M., A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry,  Vol. 2 3rd. ed.

Thanks very much.  In fact, (7) is not in my mind, sinc in different paper, (7) may be different.  Before the end of yesterday I had the idea that I could use (1) to figure out what kind of (7) Wiki was used.  Thanks again.

I revised my calculations, but they're still a little off.  Could you help me figure out what the problem is ?

@EnhaoLan See the comments to OP. I might go through all my books and compile a list that shows which author uses which convention. But remember it is "just" about index placement in the tensor components $R_{ijk}{}^l$ which is always a convention. The Riemann tensor itself is written in index-free / coordinate-free notation as $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ of which I never saw another sign convention. Lastly: if the author of a paper is unclear about $R_{ijk}{}^l$ consider throwing the paper into the bin.

I am too weak. Although Hamilton unclear about $R_{ijk}^l$ in The Ricci flow on surfaces, he omit the process which need $R_{ijk}^l$ and only unfold the node of proof which is  index-free.  But in some book, for example do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_Y\nabla_X Z - \nabla_X\nabla_YZ +\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$.

@EnhaoLan thanks for pointing that out! Lots of minus signs to keep track of. This makes one wonder what sign of  the scalar curvature of $S^2$ those authors  obtain. Btw: Hamilton's papers should be exempt from being thrown into a bin :)

The symbols of Riemannian geometry are so confusing. Today, I see $R_{ij}=g^{pq}R_{jpqk}$ (In fact, I take hour to guess it.). Since Hamilton's paper is brief,  I need to find references, which have different symbols. Really bad. Let's me play PC game to happy a little.

@EnhaoLan No. That $R_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor. Probably 150 years old. Edit: Either Hamilton's paper must go to the bin now (contrary to what I said before) or you copied that formula wrong: There cannot be a $k$ on the RHS and an $i$ on the LHS.

I copy wrong. It is $R_{jk}= g^{pq}R_{jpqk}$. One minus sign difference with normal sign.

This is why you have to choose your own notation conventions and rewrite each calculation you see in a book or paper in your own notation. This is the only way to compare formulas from two different sources.
